# :hover pseudo-class after :after pseudo-class. What is a work-around?

Tags: html, css, angular, hover

How can I implement `:hover` pseudo-class after `:after` pseudo-class. Is there a work-around? I have a frame of `border` element with a low `opacity` property in `:after class` around the profile picture and would like to change border properties when on `:hover`.

Comment: I believe order does matter: https://martinwolf.org/before-2018/blog/2015/05/why-you-can-do-hoverafter-and-not-afterhover/

Answer (score 0):

yes we can change use this conept it will work

```
            .parentclass:hover:after {
             border:1px solid red;
             }
```